# Embedded curly brackets inside PGFplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable, braces, metadata

I have a little problem with the right curly bracket `}`.
I need to use it inside `{}` for a meta-expression in a table.
I want to use tha data as coefficient: `Q_{10}`.
So, I write in the first term: `{ $Q_{ }`
Then the value `(10)` comes, and the closing expression: `{ } }`
But, obviously, close with the first right brace.

I'm trying to configure a table on PGFPlotsTable with a subindex of two digits in this way (without the braces, that works with single digit parameters)

```
\pgfplotstableset{
    columns/q/.style={int detect,column type=r, column name=\textsc{Q},
            postproc cell content/.append style={
                    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$Q_}{$}},
    },
...
}
```

Is there a way to write `}` into braces without considering this character part of the language?
Any suggestion?
It seems diabolic for me :S

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Does writing `\}` help?

Comment: I'm afraid, do not. I also try '}.

Comment: With this, I get something like a brace as subindex. But nice suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` to enclose the cell content in curly braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    columns/q/.style={int detect,column type=r, column name=\textsc{Q},
            postproc cell content/.append style={
                    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={$Q_\bgroup}{\egroup$}},
    },
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{table.dat}
x,q
1,11
2,22
3,33
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{table.dat}\table
\pgfplotstabletypeset\table
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It also works perfectly in my document.